# How to get the uncommit changes form master to another branch without trace

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

[This is a screen from SourceTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzxyC.png)

You can see in it I have 3 branches, the "Interface" for  the visual, the "Developpement" for the development and the master when "Interface" and "Developpement" works fine.
But I just worked three hours on the master branch and not on "Developpement".

Can you tell me how to move the uncommited change without proof of my error on master branch.

I think I can commit and merge --no-ff but we can see my bad way to work in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git stash
git checkout develop
git stash pop
```

You may have conflicts to resolve, but you can resolve these manually.

Comment: And if you haven't modified files that are different in the branch, you can simply do `git checkout develop`.

Comment: I do stash -> checkout -> stash pop but all my develop branch was disappear like a fast-forward merge, and this is not what I want. Now I try to revert the stash pop...

Comment: Can you send an image of sourcetree?

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, there are a conflict with sourcetree when you use also the terminal. In the terminal I checkout developpement but after this Sourcetree show the graph of developpement but we can read we are on the master branch. And that is a fake...

Comment: Close sourcetree and do this all from git bash.